# Best way to refresh graph without page refresh (Python Django, ajax)

Tags: python, ajax, django, graph, refresh

A bit of a general question - I am looking for ways to refresh a graph on a Django page based on user choices. The page has a graph, a few drop boxes where you can select parameters and a refresh button. Currently, I can capture the selections via ajax to my Django view and generate new data from database for the graph. I now need to feed that newly-generated data back into the graph and refresh it without a page refresh. Could anyone recommend the best methods of doing this?

Comment: Questions about "best way" are always tricky. You also don't say how you are generating the graph. Bokeh does what you want by attaching event handlers to widgets, and then refreshing the data source of the graph. See for instance the [Stocks example](https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/stocks).

Comment: I have not yet finalised my graph choice as it needs to be able to do what I want. The example you linked seems to be doing exactly that so I will have a look at Bokeh, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery to refresh graph without refreshing page.

I am using chart.js to create graph. first create a graph and on change event get updated data using Ajax URL call and assign values to chart data sets.
/** Graph Start Here */

```
window.chart = null;
$(document).on('change', '.graph-year-earning', function () {
    var year = $(this).val();
    $.get($('.graph-ajaxload-context').data('href'), { 'year': year, 'number': Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000 - 10 + 1) + 10) }, function (response) {
        window.chart.data.labels = response.labels;
        window.chart.data.datasets[0].soldProductLabel = response.product_sold_label;
        window.chart.data.datasets[0].totalCommissionLabel = response.monthly_commission_label;
        window.chart.data.datasets[0].dataLabel = response.your_share_label;

        if (response.total_commission == 0) {
            window.chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = 0;
            window.chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = 140000;
        } else {
            window.chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = '';
            window.chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = '';
        }

        $.each(response.data, function (index, value) {
            window.chart.data.datasets[0].soldProduct[index] = value[2];
            window.chart.data.datasets[0].data[index] = Math.round(value[0]);
        });
        window.chart.update();
        $(".txt-total-commission-by-year").html(response.total_commission)
        $('.graph-ajaxload-context .inline-loader').hide();
    });
});
if ($('.graph-ajaxload-context').length > 0) {
    showLoader()
    $('.graph-year-earning').trigger('change');
    var ctx = $('#userEarningGraph');
    window.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                soldProductLabel: '',
                soldProduct: [],
                dataLabel: '',
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: '#ADAEB1',
                hoverBackgroundColor: '#48C6B9'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 8,
                        userCallback: function (value, index, values) {
                            value = value.toString();
                            value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                            value = value.join(',');
                            var currency_code = ' ₩'
                            if ($('.graph-ajaxload-context').data('currency-code') && $('.graph-ajaxload-context').data('currency-code') != 'None') {
                                currency_code = $('.graph-ajaxload-context').data('currency-code')
                            }
                            return value + ' ' + currency_code;
                        }
                    },
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        var soldProduct = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].soldProduct[tooltipItem.index];
                        var soldProductLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].soldProductLabel;
                        var dataPro = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        var dataLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].dataLabel;
                        return [soldProductLabel + ':' + soldProduct, dataLabel + ':' + dataPro + ' ₩',];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '.showgraph', function (e) {
    $('.graph-year-earning').trigger('change');
});
/** Graph End Here */
```

Comment: @blitz please upvote if answer is usefull. So that other can see usefull answer on top.